# UnknownHostException raised on calling ressource URL with RouteLocatorBuilder

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I have to use spring-cloud-gateway.
I got some trouble to configure just a simple spring-boot project with it form this tutoriel https://spring.io/guides/gs/gateway/

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class MarouteApplication {

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator maRoute(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(p -> p
                        .path("/get")
                        .filters(f -> f.addRequestHeader("Hello", "World"))
                        .uri("http://httpbin.org:80"))
                .route(p -> p
                        .path("/bling")
                        .uri("http://localhost:9090/test"))
                .build();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/test")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getPerso() throws Exception {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("{\"value\":\"OK\"}");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MarouteApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.yaml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      proxy:
        host: %MY_PROXY_BUT_ITS_HIDDEN%
        port: 8080
      routes:
        - id: rewritepath_route
          uri: http://example.org
          predicates:
            - Path=/foo/**

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
  metrics:
    web:
      server:
        auto-time-requests: true
server:
  port: 9090
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.maroute</groupId>
    <artifactId>maroute</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>maroute</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

So I have three route, two configured through RouteLocatorBuilder. And one configured through application.yaml.

Endpoint http://localhost:9090/test works.

For route /get I got:

```
2019-09-09 16:06:46.026 ERROR 5469 --- [or-http-epoll-3] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [95d74b07] 500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/get"

java.net.UnknownHostException: httpbin.org
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1248) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:146) ~[netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:143) ~[netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.addressByName(SocketUtils.java:143) ~[netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.DefaultNameResolver.doResolve(DefaultNameResolver.java:43) ~[netty-resolver-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:63) ~[netty-resolver-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:55) ~[netty-resolver-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:57) ~[netty-resolver-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:32) ~[netty-resolver-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.AbstractAddressResolver.resolve(AbstractAddressResolver.java:108) ~[netty-resolver-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:204) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect(Bootstrap.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.connect(Bootstrap.java:120) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.pool.SimpleChannelPool.connectChannel(SimpleChannelPool.java:263) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.pool.SimpleChannelPool.acquireHealthyFromPoolOrNew(SimpleChannelPool.java:175) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.pool.SimpleChannelPool.acquire(SimpleChannelPool.java:160) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$Pool.acquire(PooledConnectionProvider.java:258) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.11.RELEASE.jar:0.8.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$Pool.acquire(PooledConnectionProvider.java:252) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.11.RELEASE.jar:0.8.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider.disposableAcquire(PooledConnectionProvider.java:204) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.11.RELEASE.jar:0.8.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider.lambda$acquire$2(PooledConnectionProvider.java:162) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.11.RELEASE.jar:0.8.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:57) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.lambda$subscribe$0(HttpClientConnect.java:327) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.11.RELEASE.jar:0.8.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:57) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3858) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryPredicate$RetryPredicateSubscriber.resubscribe(FluxRetryPredicate.java:123) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRetryPredicate.subscribe(MonoRetryPredicate.java:51) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.subscribe(HttpClientConnect.java:330) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.11.RELEASE.jar:0.8.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany.subscribe(MonoFlatMapMany.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:7923) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeek.subscribe(MonoPeek.java:71) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3858) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekFuseable.subscribe(MonoPeekFuseable.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDoFinally.subscribe(MonoDoFinally.java:47) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3858) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:275) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:849) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1515) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:275) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:849) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:192) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1515) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFilterWhen$MonoFilterWhenMain.onNext(MonoFilterWhen.java:140) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2071) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFilterWhen$MonoFilterWhenMain.onSubscribe(MonoFilterWhen.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFilterWhen.subscribe(MonoFilterWhen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeek.subscribe(MonoPeek.java:71) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3858) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:442) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:244) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDematerialize$DematerializeSubscriber.onNext(FluxDematerialize.java:114) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDematerialize$DematerializeSubscriber.onNext(FluxDematerialize.java:42) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:243) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:201) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDematerialize$DematerializeSubscriber.request(FluxDematerialize.java:157) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:229) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDematerialize$DematerializeSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxDematerialize.java:88) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:63) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDematerialize.subscribe(FluxDematerialize.java:39) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefer.subscribe(FluxDefer.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap.subscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext.subscribe(MonoNext.java:40) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap.subscribe(MonoMap.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap.subscribe(MonoMap.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3858) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:442) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:212) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:63) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap.subscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext.subscribe(MonoNext.java:40) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal.subscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3858) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekFuseable.subscribe(MonoPeekFuseable.java:70) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal.subscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerHandle.onStateChange(HttpServerHandle.java:64) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.11.RELEASE.jar:0.8.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServerBind$ChildObserver.onStateChange(TcpServerBind.java:226) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.11.RELEASE.jar:0.8.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:442) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.11.RELEASE.jar:0.8.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:91) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.11.RELEASE.jar:0.8.11.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:161) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.11.RELEASE.jar:0.8.11.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:328) ~[netty-codec-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:302) ~[netty-codec-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1421) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:794) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.39.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:424) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.39.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:326) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.39.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918) ~[netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar:4.1.39.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

I got the same error for /foo route:

```
2019-09-09 16:07:58.830 ERROR 5469 --- [or-http-epoll-3] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [95d74b07] 500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/foo"

java.net.UnknownHostException: example.org
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1248) ~[na:na]
```

And for /bling route I got 413 code error (Request Entity Too Large)

I have suspected my proxy to no allow external sites so I configure It in application.yaml. Result does not change.

If anybody has any idea

Comment: does httpbin.org:80 work in your browser?

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer.
Yeah, It works in my browser.
I tried others endpoints of this site in my project and in my browser and it works too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I can't access to external websites due to my professional environnement that not allow that. In others computers (like my personnal one) it is working.

The route works if I redirect to others local endpoint. You can not reroute to the same port endpoint that explains 413 error.
So I started new API on another port and it is working.
It is important to know that for this route:

```
    @Bean
    public RouteLocator maRoute(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(p -> p
                        .path("/foo")
                        .uri("http://localhost:8080/test"))
                .build();
    }
```

The route redirect to http://localhost:8080/foo
So if you have no endpoint in http:localhost:8080/foo you will have 404.
You can use many way to redirect to 8080/test like:

```
    @Bean
    public RouteLocator maRoute(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(p -> p
                        .path("/test")
                        .uri("http://localhost:8080"))
                .build();
    }
```

or if you want to keep redirect with /foo endpoint

```
    @Bean
    public RouteLocator maRoute(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(p -> p
                        .path("/foo")
                        .filters(f -> f.rewritePath("/foo", "/test"))
                        .uri("http://localhost:8080"))
                .build();
    }
```

In addition, if you want to know if your route redirect to what you really expect you can configure logging level in you application.yaml or properties:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.cloud.gateway: TRACE
    org.springframework.http.server.reactive: DEBUG
    org.springframework.web.reactive: DEBUG
    reactor.ipc.netty: DEBUG
    reactor.netty: DEBUG
```